# Convert List of list into tuple of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I have a list of `2x1` matrices like:

```
[[[2.3], [2.4]], [[1.7], [1.6]], [[2.02], [2.33]]]
```

I need to convert it into a tuple of tuples, like:

```
((2.3,2.4),(1.7,1.6),(2.02,2.33))
```

I know I can loop through the list and convert it manually , trying to check if there is a better-optimized way of doing it.

Comment: Convert your loop into a comprehension

Comment: Why do you have a numpy tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way using numpy indexing and slicing that outer dimension.

```
ma =  [[[2.3], [2.4]], [[1.7], [1.6]], [[2.02], [2.33]]]
ama=np.array(ma) #incase it wasn't a numpy array since you mentioned numpy in tags
tuple(map(tuple,ama[:, :, 0].tolist()))
```

Output:

```
((2.3, 2.4), (1.7, 1.6), (2.02, 2.33))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using nested list comprehension:

```
orig = [[[2.3], [2.4]], [[1.7], [1.6]], [[2.02], [2.33]]]
>>> tuple(tuple(e[0] for e in l) for l in orig)
((2.3, 2.4), (1.7, 1.6), (2.02, 2.33))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[[2.3], [2.4]], [[1.7], [1.6]], [[2.02], [2.33]]]
tuple(tuple(l2[0] for l2 in l1) for l1 in L)
```

Output:

```
((2.3, 2.4), (1.7, 1.6), (2.02, 2.33))
```